# Mips to C translation, two for-cycles

Tags: c, mips

I recently started exploring MIPS and I am not sure if I understand this code well.

```
  addi s4, $0, 0    // s4 = 0; 
  addi s1, $0, 7    // s1 = 7;
  addi t2, $0, 7    // t2 = 7;
  addi s0, $0, 1    // s0 = 1;
  addi t1, $0, 21   // t1 = 21;
L1: addi s1, $0, 0  // s1 has new value s1 = 0;?
L2: addi s4, s4, 7  // s4 += 7;
  addi s1, s1, 1    // s1 += 1;
  slt t3, s1, t2    // t3 = (s1 < t2) ? 1 : 0;
  bne t3, $0, L2    // if t3 != 0 go to L2 
  nop
  addi s0, s0, 1    // s0 =+ 1;
  slt t3, s0, t1    // t3 = (s0 < t1) ? 1 : 0; 
  bne t3, $0, L1    // if t3 != 0 go to L1
  nop
L3: nop
```

The question is what's the value of s4 at the end of this assembler code.
I imagine the C translation would be:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
      s4 += 7;
```

However I am concerned with this line.

```
L1: addi s1, $0, 0
```

It seems to me like I override the s1 = 7; with s1 = 0;. Does this happens every iteration on L1 or just once?. The reason why am I asking is because the line `L2: addi s4, s4, 7`happens every iteration of the L2 cycle.

I am not sure If my translation to C is correct due to my assumptions. Thanks in advance for clarification of what's happening in this code.

Comment: Of course `j = 0` happens for every iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: It should be somewhat easy to put this into SPIM/MARS/... MIPS asm+emulator (especially if you will have to use one of them later for future tasks, familiarizing early with them is then not wasted time), and try to run it instruction by instruction in debugger. The override of value maybe feels weird, because the original `s1 = 7` is not used anywhere, but that's how it is. Once you jump with CPU to "`L1:`", there's no way to avoid that instruction, so of course it will be executed every time the `pc` is equal `L1` at the beginning of tick. The C version *looks* correct, but run it to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jester answered in comment, the `s1 = 0;` happens every iteration.

The C translation is sort of correct, but the more accurate C version would be:

```
s4 = 0;
s1 = 7;
s0 = 1;
do {
    s1 = 0;
    do {
        s4 += 7;
    } while (++s1 < 7);
} while (++s0 < 21);
```

This should produce the same result in your case, but the difference is in the principle of `for` vs `do ... while` loops, where the `for` does the first check ahead of executing first iteration, while `do ... while` does execute the body statement at least once even when the condition is `false` since beginning.

The `for` in assembly often has the compare + conditional branch at the beginning of loop code, and ends with unconditional branch back to that start (at least when written by human with readability in mind, C/C++ compilers may unroll it a bit for performance or even pre-calculate some parts when the calculation is stable at compile time, like this one - a good C compiler would compile this into `return 980;`).

At least godbolt.org for MIPS gcc 5.4 (-O3) does produce:

```
    j       $31
    li      $2,980                  # 0x3d4
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Ped7g. Now I get it.